# How to export Attached File Count column in a query

Tags: excel, tfs, export

Using TFS 2017 (and in DevOps) I have a query of work items. I added the column "Attached File Count" to my query. It shows up fine in the display but it will not show up in the exported excel file.

I have tried moving its position and nothing has worked. Columns before and after it work fine.

Comment: i have also tried editing the WIT template but so far no luck

Answer (score 0):

This should be an expected behavior. After go through the **available columns** in excel from Columns setting.

[image]

We could find there is not any column called "**Attached File Count**",  that's why it couldn't show up in Excel.

You may have to check this column either in web portal or manually add them in your exported excel file.

Comment: As you can see in the screen shot you provided, of which i see exactly the same thing, the "Attached File Count" column is not listed there.

i did notice while exploring all the options that this is a "system" field. I don't know if that's the issue or not but its just not available.

My only option at this point, baring any revelation, is to use the API calls to get the data I want. Not ideal as I need users to be able to export data to excel on their own without my intervention.

Comment: @CJ Exactly, not all fields are supported to list in available columns when you export work items to excel. After go through some docs, to be honest, I didn't find any evidence if this related to system field. Yes, using rest api  will return all fields' info. This should be a workaround. `Not ideal as I need users to.... on their own without my intervention.` You could use a powershell script to invoke corresponding Rest API to fetch any related info. You could add some input option which make users more easy to handle it, so they just need to run the script without your intervention.

Comment: Due to other constraints I have not had a chance to get back to this issue. I have stated putting together a ps script to extract the data as i need it. I will be happy to post it once complete.

Comment: @CJ Thanks for getting back. Sure please feel free to share here, always better when you fix it yourself; as you understand how it works!:)