# How to export Attached File Count column from Azure DevOps Query

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm using Azure DevOps. I wrote a query to get work items. And I want to see info about attached files, so I added "Attached File Count" columns. When I run query, it was worked fine. And I saw results like below image

[image]

But I tried to export with "Open in Excel" Extension.

[image]

"Attached File Count" column was not shown in Excel.

[image]

And then I checked available columns in Excel -> Team Tab. But I cannot see it in there.

[image]

Finally, I found old post [How to Export Attached File Count ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856636/how-to-export-attached-file-count-column-in-a-query), but there is no solution answer in it.